# What is the closest approximation to R's nlminb in Matlab?

Tags: r, matlab, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Does Matlab have an equivalent to [`nlminb`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/nlminb.html) in R?

I realize that `lsqcurvefit` is available in Matlab, but I specifically want a function that uses a derivative-based method, ideally exactly the same one as `nlminb` uses.

`nlminb` is described in [this Stats.StackExhange.com answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9535/when-should-i-not-use-rs-nlm-function-for-mle).

I do not want to use the `'trust-region-refelective'` method emplyed by `lsqcurvefit` for constrained problems.

Comment: Are you actually performing maximum likelihood estimation as in the linked Stats.StackExhange.com question/answer?

Comment: No I'm performing a least squares fit but I want to test a new optimizer against a derivative based one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab's [`fmincon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fmincon.html) uses [Quasi-Newton methods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-Newton_method) with constraints if the appropriate [`'Algorithm'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/choosing-a-solver.html#bsbwxm7) option is specified. Apparently R's `nlminb` is based on the [`L-BFGS-B` code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited-memory_BFGS#L-BFGS-B). Using the `'interior-point'` algorithm this method of approximating the Hessian [can be specified](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/writing-objective-functions.html#btt3sy0):

```
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','Hessian','lbfgs');
```

Unless you're running out of memory, the value of using `'lbfgs'` over the default `'bfgs'` is questionable. Try them all.

Comment: Would using lsqcurvefit with the levenberg-marquardt algorithm (i.e. I drop the constraints but make sure the initial guesses are well within the desired boundries) also approximate nlminb well?  Or is fmincon closer?

Comment: No idea. Levenberg-Marquardt is not a quasi-Newton method. It's a combination of [Gauss-Newton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss–Newton_algorithm) and gradient descent. It is very robust. `lsqcurvefit` is designed for fitting data, so if that's your application try it. I don't see why you could use the default `'trust-region-reflective'` either, unless one of the [required conditions to use it is not met](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/lsqcurvefit.html#f192109), which the function will warn you about.

Comment: Hey there when I try running this with fminunc I get: ??? Error using ==> optimset at 223
Invalid value for OPTIONS parameter Algorithm:
 must be 'active-set', 'trust-region-reflective', 'interior-point', 'interior-point-convex',
 'levenberg-marquardt', 'trust-region-dogleg', 'lm-line-search', or 'sqp'.

Error in ==> Optimal_Lambda_fmin at 64
options=optimset('Algorithm','quasi-newton','HessUpdate','bfgs','MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-16,'MaxIter',10000); Although 'quasi-newton' is shown as an available algo for the 2013b edition I am using 2011a!!

Comment: Do you know which if any of the above algorithms is the same as nlminb?

Comment: I can get it to run with: options=optimset('Algorithm','interior-point','Hessian','lbfgs','MaxFunEvals',10000,'TolFun',1e-16,'MaxIter',10000);   [cn(:,ii,jj),residual(:,ii,jj),exitflag(:,ii,jj),output(:,ii,jj)]=fmincon(@(l)NSS_fmin(l,mats,mats2,y2,yc_m),L0,[],[],[],[],lbn,ubn,[],options); but would prefer to run it with the same algo as in nlminb but without any restrictions

Comment: If you're using an older version of Matlab, you should always read the documentation for *your version* (`doc fminunc` in this case) not the one online unless you know they're the same. You can find [archived documentation for older versions here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/doc-archives.html).

Comment: In R2011a with `fminunc`, [here are the actual choices for algorithm](http://www.mathworks.com/help/releases/R2011a/toolbox/optim/ug/brhkghv-18.html#bsbwxz1). Despite what the error says, you can't actually set an `'Algorthm'` property for this solver, only if the the problem is large or medium scale, which will change things. The large scale method requires you to specify a gradient. If you use the medium scale method, the you can specify `'bfgs'` for the `'HessUpdate'` property, which may be closest to `nlminb`.